# Phpunit close cmd windows when get error

Tags: php, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

when i use  this cmd, i want it to stay opened even if i get error on page execution

```
phpunit C:\wamp\www\webdriver\folder\file.php
```

but phpunit close the dos windows
How to force  windows stand ?

Answer (score 0):

Long ago I have written this simple file and used it in [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) ini setting to deal with this problem on Windows:

```
<?php

if (PHP_SAPI === "cli") {
    function __php_cli_press_any_key_shutdown(){
        echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."Press any key to continue...";
        exec('pause');
    }

    register_shutdown_function('__php_cli_press_any_key_shutdown');
}
```

Comment: can you show me how to use it 
i did this on php.ini
auto_prepend_file =C:/wamp/www/ok.php(this contains your code)
and in file.php

i added require('ok.php');
but dont work what's my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct php.ini? Apache and cli may use different paths to seek for php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I simply open a DOS window and run my batch file (which calls the PHPUnit command line with some current parameters so I can use it on different projects).  As I ran it from a DOS window, there is not a closing of the window, unless some code (batch file) calls an exit.  I do not believe PHPUnit is closing the window.

Comment: i found other way with way to save it on txt file
phpunit C:\wamp\www\webdriver\folder\file.php > c:\output.txt